# How to generate python tree using command line?

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I already know how to generate java tree using command line

```
java -cp ".;D:\lib\antlr\antlr-4.9.2-complete.jar" org.antlr.v4.gui.TestRig Java8 compilationUnit Test2.java -tree
```

Thank you friend for your help
but...
How to generate python tree using command line?
I imitated the above statement but couldn't succeed

I am using Python3Lexer.g4 and Python3Parser.g4 in g4

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPek1.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TestRig expects the name of the grammar (in this case `Python3`) and the name of your start rule.  Good candidates are generally those rules that end in `EOF` since they are intended to parse all of you input.  The Python grammar has `file_input` and `eval_input`.  So I would expect `file_input` to be your answer.

try:

```
java -cp ".;D:\lib\antlr\antlr-4.9.2-complete.jar" org.antlr.v4.gui.TestRig Python3 file_input pythonPgm.py -tree
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, I am a rookie, but I have learned it now.